# Why does wsgiref have such redundant statements?

Tags: python, wsgiref

When I read the source code of wsgiref (version 0.1), the class [SimpleHandler](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-wsgiref/0.1.2/handlers_8py_source.html) which contained two functions `_write` and `_flush` confused me. I think `self._write = self.stdout.write` and `self._flush = self.stdout.flush` are redundant. When I commented it out, it seems to still work. So why is it written like this?

```
def _write(self,data):
    self.stdout.write(data)
    self._write = self.stdout.write

def _flush(self):
    self.stdout.flush()
    self._flush = self.stdout.flush
```

Comment: If I had to guess, so you can override the methods from a subclass. If you want to be sure, you might want to contact a dev directly.